# How to process large XML's in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel 2.14.0 version.
I have created a route to poll a directory containing XML's and then pass it on to activeMQ broker.

```
from("file://D:/test?sortBy=file:modified&include=test_.*.xml$&noop=true").to("activemq:queue:temp.XMLFileQueue");
```

It works fine with small XML's (upto 20Mb) but if the filesize is more it gives `OutOfMemoryError`.

To avoid this, I changed the route as below

```
from("file://D:/test?sortBy=file:modified&include=test_.*.xml$&noop=true").split(body().tokenizeXML("ship", "ships")).streaming().to("activemq:queue:temp.XMLFileQueue");
```

After doing this, I see that Camel is creating multiple threads to process each chunk as a result of which I am facing some new issues. As per my logic after the XML is processed, it should be deleted - earlier it was single thread and so it was fine but now due to many threads, 1 thread deletes the file but another thread still tries to process the file and throws `FileNotFoundException`.

How to avoid this? Please let me know the proper way to process large XML's with single thread.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: Try upgrade to latest 2.14.x release - there has been some improvements and fixes to the stream caching when using the splitter eips etc.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, an option would be to implement the [Claim Check Pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/StoreInLibrary.html). See also [Apache Camel: Claim Check](http://camel.apache.org/claim-check.html)

Comment: Did you try and set the heap size of the jvm? Also where in your logic do you do the delete? I cannot see it in the file component as it is set to `noop=true`. I would limit the amount of thread using a thread pool and then only after the splitter has finished delete the file. Hard to say with your current example as I cannot see where you actually delete the file.